# Cant access attribute NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, core-data

i have a problem accessing an attribute in a NSManagedObjectContext.

I have created and subclassed the "Module"-class. 
If i want to create the module, everything is fine.

but if i want to access the "state"-attribute ig got:

```
2015-10-26 10:05:46.041 StudyGraph[84862:23335247] -[StudyGraph.Module processingState]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f97d2e3bb00
```

This is the model.
[image: Model]

ManagedObject-Subclass:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

enum ModuleState: Int16 {
    case Open
    case Active
    case Done
}

class Module: NSManagedObject {

    var moduleState: ModuleState {
        get {
            return ModuleState(rawValue: processingState)!  // Here it stops !!!
        }
        set {
            processingState = newValue.rawValue
        }
    }

    class func create(context: NSManagedObjectContext, title: String) -> Module? {
        if let newModule = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Module", inManagedObjectContext: context) as? Module {
            //  Set values
            newModule.title = title

            //  Save
            do {
                try newModule.managedObjectContext?.save()
            } catch {
                print("Error while saving new Module.")
            }

            // return
            print(newModule)
            return newModule
        }
        return nil
    }

    func progress() -> Float {
        return 0.25
    }
}
```

Extension:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

extension Module {

    @NSManaged var processingState: Int16
    @NSManaged var title: String?

}
```

Code which calls the getter:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ModuleCell") as? ModuleTableViewCell {
            if let cellObject = dataManager.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Module {
                cell.titleLabel?.text = cellObject.title
                cell.progressIndicator?.progress = cellObject.progress()
                print(cellObject.moduleState)
                return cell
            }

        }

        let dummy = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "DUMMY")
        dummy.textLabel?.text = "DUMMY"
        return dummy
    }
```

in DataManager:

```
func objectAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSManagedObject? {
    if let frc = self.fetchedResultsController {
        if let obj = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? NSManagedObject {
            return obj
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the defined attribute `state` in the model you have to declare a `@NSManaged` variable in the subclass. Core Data creates the appropriate setters and getters implicitly.

```
@NSManaged var state: Int16
```

And declare a second variable to convert the enum value to `Int16` and vice versa.

```
var moduleState: ModuleState {
  get {
    return ModuleState(rawValue: state)!
  }
  set {
    state = newValue.rawValue
  }
}
```

To avoid type casting declare the enum type as `Int16`

```
enum ModuleState: Int16 { … }
```

Instead of your function `getModuleState()` you can just use the variable `moduleState`

I recommend also to declare the attribute `state` in the model as non-optional

Comment: did you uncheck the `Optional` checkbox in the attribute inspector?

Comment: Maybe `state` is a reserved keyword somewhere, try a different name. And as in Objective-C `new` has also a special meaning, I recommend to change the variable `new` to `newItem` or similar.

Comment: Ok. "new" is now "newModule". "state" is now "processingState". Same issue.

Comment: Weird. I'm using a similar class with an enum declaration which works fine

Comment: Basically the same code (attribute in Core Data, a subclass, an enum and a variable to convert enum to `Int`). The error might be in the code portion which calls the getter of the property.

Comment: Updated the question with the code snippets for that.

Comment: Ok. So i will create a new clean Project and copy file von file and Check where it goes wrong -.- thanks for your help

Comment: So, like I mentioned. New Project -> Same Code -> Works !